# javascript video full screen and rotate by 270deg

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I have a button and once clicked, video on webpage will be shown in full screen mode. It work perfectly fine.

I have a requirement when the video should be rotated by 270deg in full screen mode. In non full screen mode, the using style transform with rotate(270deg) is working fine. The same doesn't work in full screen mode.

Any way to achieve this? I am using chrome browser.

Comment: Are you implementing your video with `<video>` tag?

Comment: Full screen is fullscreen for the whole screen or just a document?

Comment: Yes. I put it in video tag as below.                                                           
 <video id="testvideo" style="transform: rotate(270deg); width: 450px; height: 450px; " autoplay poster="images/operator2.jpg" class="" ></video>           I want just the video to be full screen with rotate intact.

Comment: And the fullscreen is on the whole monitor or just for browser area?

Comment: Would prefer to put on whole screen.

Comment: Try this: `video:-webkit-full-screen { transform: rotate(9deg) !important; }` Would be good if I know how are you setting fullscreen. With default video controls on video element? For mozilla: `video:-moz-full-screen` and default: `video:fullscreen`

Comment: Thanks for response but the suggested settings are not working. May be for full screen the transform is not considered. Were you able to get it working?